# SMS not detected in cordova 12 Android App by using cordova-plugin-sms-receive

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using cordova 12 for my Android App, which should get and read the SMS, and reply the answers.
From some reason, the device (Android 10) I'm using for debug (connected via USB to my computer), is getting the SMS but the app is not catching them.

This is the manifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
</manifest>
```

Is there any limitation which is blocking it?

I added the relevant plugins which was used in my App (sending SMS - Working well, Receiving SMS - Now working)

It seems like the startWatch succeeded, but the event of "onSMSArrived" is not detected, or not fired at all.

This is the log:
[INFO:CONSOLE(45)] "SMS_WATCHING_STARTED", source: https://localhost/js/main.js (45)

This is the relevant code in my JS file, main.js (which contains most of the App logic):

```
try {
                    cordova.plugins.SMSReceive.startWatch(function(strSuccess) {
                        console.log(strSuccess);
                    }, function(strError) {
                        console.warn(strError);
                    });
                    
                    document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', function(smsReceived) {
                        console.log('SMS Received: ' + smsReceived.body);
                        this.sendResponseToContact(smsReceived.address, smsReceived.body);
                        this.send({
                            method: 'sms_received',
                            id: this.kindergartenId,
                            message: smsReceived.body,
                            number: smsReceived.address
                        });
                    });
                    
                }catch (e) {
                    console.log('SMS Receive error: ' + e.message);
                    this.send({
                        method: 'error',
                        id: this.kindergartenId,
                        msg: e.message
                    });
                }
```